# Spring Boot maven project unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, build

The project is working fine on the VScode, but when I try to build as **.jar** and run in EC2 ubuntu instance or in my local, I am facing the following error message when I try to run by this command.

```
java -jar project-name.jar
```

```
13:54:04.899 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332)
        at com.ndb.auction.AuctionApplication.main(AuctionApplication.java:21)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory bean.
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.getWebServerFactory(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:210)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:180)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AuctionApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuctionApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @Bean
    GraphQLScalarType uploadScalarType() {
        return ApolloScalars.Upload;
    }
}
```

```java
public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AuctionApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you building the jar.

Comment: I used VScode extenstion to build jar file

Comment: You need to run maven or gradle with the spring boot plugin to build a proper jar.

Comment: I tried spring tool suite to build project, and it is working now. I will try your way to build in vscode. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with building jar in VScode, I tried **Spring Tool Suite**(spring-tool-suite-3.9.12.RELEASE-e4.15.0-win32-x86_64) to build jar file, and it is working now.